# What kind of conjugation is「お召しなすって」?

Tags: keigo

This is from 茨海{ばらうみ}小学校 by 宮沢賢治, probably written almost 100 years ago.

> 「どうぞスリッパをお召しなすって。只今{ただいま}校長に申しますから。」

My question is about お召しなすって. I think 召す is 尊敬語 meaning "to wear" in this case. I know there are some patterns like お～になる and お～する. Is なする a corruption of なさる?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[為さる](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E7%82%BA%E3%81%95%E3%82%8B): To do (same なさる as used in ごめん**なさい**).

[召す](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E5%8F%AC%E3%81%99): To wear; to don; to put on (among other definitions).

なすって seems to be old Tokyo dialect, same meaning as なさって (Fairly obscure nowadays).

'Please put (some/these) slippers on.' 「どうぞスリッパを [お召しなさって・お履きなさって」] 、」